# Determine whether W is a subspace of the vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine whether $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$. Give a complete proof using the subspace theorem, or give a specific example to show that some subspace property fails.

(a) Let $V = \mathcal{F}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $V$ is vector space of all real valued functions on the interval $[a,b]$, $W = \{f \in \mathcal{F}([a,b],\mathbb{R}) \mid f(6) = 10\}$ where $a \leq 6 \leq b$.

Comment: What are your thoughts. It is expected to show your efforts here

Comment: $W$ is not a subspace. since additive identity does not belongs to $W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W is not a subspace. Take any f belongs to W, take g=f+f should belongs to W. But g(6)=f(6)+f(6)=10+10=20. g does not belongs to W. Therefore W is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this is not a vector subspace. It violates closure. In general, you can always check to see if $W$ is a subspace by verifying $W\subset V$ (trivial) and that $W$ itself forms a vector space. Note that if we take
$g(6)$=$f_1(6)$+$f_2(6)$, $g(x)$ does not lie in $W$, so $W$ does not form a subspace.

Also, the zero vector does not belong to $W$, which is also a requirement for it to be a subspace.